# Is there a pattern to combine two classes provided by third party library?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two classes from third party libraries that have very similar functionalities lets call them class Car and class Bike. I cannot directly make changes to the class but I want to be able to abstract them so that I can use them like so

```
public bool drive(IDriveable vehicle)
{
    vehicle.Start();
    vehicle.Shift(Gear.Drive);
    vehicle.Accelerate();
    //so on...
}
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: `CarWrapper` which implements `IDriveable` and contains an instance of `Car` (as field / property). Same for `BikeWrapper`.

Comment: Derive from Car or Bike and add your functions or override its functions with yours.

Comment: @nish in the interfaces like Accelerate() would I be able to call something like this.base()?

Comment: @ProgrammerAdept You would yes (although in the *class* not *interface*).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is what you're looking for.

> In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) The decorator pattern is often useful for adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle, as it allows functionality to be divided between classes with unique areas of concern.[2] The decorator pattern is structurally nearly identical to the chain of responsibility pattern, the difference being that in a chain of responsibility, exactly one of the classes handles the request, while for the decorator, all classes handle the request.

I would create a `BikeDecorator`, and a `CarDecorator` that both implement `IDriveable`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new interface IDriveable which contains all functions that you need to call. In this case are, for example, Start and Accelerate. Then, creating 2 classes which are Car and Bike inherit BaseCar, BaseBike and implement IDriveable. For example:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Car
{
 public void Start()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Start Car");
 }
 public void Accelerate()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Accelerate Car");
 }
}

public class Bike
{
 public void Start()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Start Bike");
 }
 public void Accelerate()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Accelerate Bike");
 }
}

interface IDriveable
{
 void Start(); 
 void Accelerate();  
}

class CarChild : Car, IDriveable
{
 //To hide the parent's function we use 'new'. We can call parent's functio by base.
 public new void Accelerate()
 {
  base.Accelerate();
  Console.WriteLine("Accelerate CarChild");
 }
}

class BikeChild: Bike, IDriveable
{
 
}
     
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  List<IDriveable> devices = new List<IDriveable>();
  devices.Add(new CarChild());
  devices.Add(new BikeChild());
  SkimAll(devices);
 }
 private static void SkimAll(List<IDriveable> devices)
 {
  foreach(var device in devices)
  {
   device.Start();
   device.Accelerate();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is the **Adapter pattern** that you need to solve your problem. As per wikipedia, Adapter pattern solves the following problems:

- How can a class be reused that does not have an interface that a client requires?
- How can classes that have incompatible interfaces work together?
- How can an alternative interface be provided for a class?

**The Adapter design pattern describes how to solve such problems:**

- Define a separate Adapter class that converts the (incompatible)
  interface of a class (Adaptee) into another interface (Target)
  clients require.
- Work through an Adapter to work with (reuse) classes that do not have
  the required interface.

Answer (score 0):

First let us suppose the third party code

```
public enum Gear
{
    Drive,
    Stop
}
```

And the third party code for Car as below

```
public class Car
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.Write($"Start Car");
    }

    public void Shift(Gear gear)
    {
        Console.Write($" Shift {gear}");
    }

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        Console.Write($" Accelerate Car");
    }
}
```

And similarly third party code for Bike as below

```
    public class Bike
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Console.Write($"Start Bike");
    }

    public void Shift(Gear gear)
    {
        Console.Write($" Shift {gear}");
    }

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        Console.Write($" Accelerate Bike");
    }
}
```

then we can define interface as below

```
interface IDriveable
{
    void Start();

    void Shift(Gear gear);

    void Accelerate();
}
```

Now we can define a class for Car as below

```
 class DriveableCar : IDriveable
{
    private Car _car;

    public DriveableCar()
    {
        _car = new Car();
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        _car.Start();
    }        
    public void Accelerate()
    {
        _car.Accelerate();
    }

    public void Shift(Gear gear)
    {
        _car.Shift(gear);
    }
}
```

For the Bike we can define another class as below

```
class DriveableBike : IDriveable
{
    private Bike _bike;

    public DriveableBike()
    {
        _bike = new Bike();
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        _bike.Start();
    }
    public void Shift(Gear gear)
    {
        _bike.Shift(gear);
    }
    public void Accelerate()
    {
        _bike.Accelerate();
    }
}
```

Now we can consume the third party code as below

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // USING THE CAR

        var car = new DriveableCar();
        car.Start();
        car.Shift(Gear.Drive);
        car.Accelerate();


        //USING THE BIKE
        var bike = new DriveableBike();
        bike.Start();
        bike.Shift(Gear.Drive);
        bike.Accelerate();



        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

@ProgrammerAdept, Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: thats decorator pattern

Comment: IMHO, I am using **composition** by injecting the third party components in our client or we can say consuming class. I have a sample of [decorator pattern](https://github.com/AJEETX/decorator_design_pattern)

Comment: you are forcing the instantiation of Car inside the DriveableCar , maybe you don't have all the information to do that. I think it will be much better if you provide the instance from outside (decorator)

Comment: Yes, as I can understand the question states that we can access the Car but not change. And I don't require any other information to instantiate. And, of course, in real scenario we can  instead inject through any DI container.

Comment: He is telling us that we can access the Car class (cause is public) . assuming you will allways be able to instantiate a Car without knowing anything is going so far.Using a dependency injection for that will be overengineering

Comment: Yes, that is why my first option was to instantiate the third-party  `Car` within the **DriveableCar**.

Comment: Imagine that Car has a variable number parameters, how will you do inside DriveableCAR ? Copy all the constructors? Why you don't prefer decroator pattern?

Comment: Not sure ,how plugging decorator here adds any value. Please advise.

Comment: By using decorator you get the Car instance injected in the constructor of DriveableCar , so you dont have to care how it is builded then you get decoupled from that. You only need a instance to work with

Comment: As I can think, that'd be over engineering since we need to add 2 abstract decorator class, each for `Car` and `Bike` and injecting these `Car and `Bike` into those abstract classes

Comment: You dont have any other way, and isn't worse than the composition you proposed

Comment: @Badulake, IMHO if objective  is achieved without 2 abstract decorator classes, I should patronize for composition than decorator. [DECORATOR CODE SAMPLE](https://gist.github.com/AJEETX/3595bd8c19ce5b6f566e753582f474e5)

Comment: But in composition you have to create the same number of classes, right? And also be care of the construction of objects tthat probably is not your responsability ;)

Comment: I am not sure if I am able to clarify. As I already stated, in composition we have 2 classes lesser than decorator. And the construction of objects shall be moved to client class which create the decorator. please find the code [ DECORATOR CODE SAMPLE](https://gist.github.com/AJEETX/3595bd8c19ce5b6f566e753582f474e5)